# Can I create a new web page by adding a new jsp to the existing web project?

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, web

As mentioned in the question, Can I create a new web page by adding a new jsp to the existing web project?

I want to create the new webpage and in the same time I want to reuse the existing resources of the old web project (java class files, etc ...)

And I want those 2 web sites to be able to access to the same Tom Cat server.

Im just a beginner in this Java web project. Any suggestion for me?

Comment: hum.., thanks then can you tell me the step I need to follow :DD
have googled around but still couldn't find a way to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But after you create a new jsp, you have to define the url mapping in the web.xml, also you can deploy those 2 web sites in the same tomcat.